# Proof for a matrix that the following is valid...

Tags: matrices

The task is the following,

Let $M$ be a matrix. Show that the minimal number of rows and columns that together contain all $1$’s of $M$ equals the size of the largest set of $1$’s in $M$, such that no two are in the same row or column.

How can I proof this?

Comment: Can you let us know what tried and where you got stuck? What methods do you know or have you learned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$R: =\{\text{set of rows and columns that together contain all 1’s of M}\}$$Let $$S: = \{\text{largest set of 1’s in M, such that no two are in the same row or column}\}$$We need at least a row or column to cover each of the $1$'s in $S$ (as each of them is in a different row and column), so $$|R| \geq |S|$$

*Claim*: There is a combination of rows and columns created by assigning either a row or a column to each $1$ in $S$ (for eg. first $1$ in $S$ is contained in a row of $R$; second in a column of $R$; etc.) that contains each of the $1$'s in $M$

Suppose there doesn't exist any, then there is *some* $1$ left out in the matrix from all the row and column indices of any combination of rows and columns in $R$. This $1$ is not in $S$ since we covered all of them by assigning either a row or column containing it.  This is a contradiction to the size of $S$ since we chose it to be the *largest* set of $1$'s with different row and column index than all others.

Comment: The proof is not quite correct I think. This issue is that the mere fact that the additional 1 (let's call it $x$) is not covered by a set of rows and columns that covers $S$ does *not* imply that $x$ can be added to $S$, i.e. that it is not in the same row as some other $1$ (let's call it $s$) that is already in $S$. After all: suppose that $R$ is so big that both the row AND the column of $s$ are in $R$, then we could have just chosen to use the column, rather than row, and thereby leave $x$ uncovered, in spite of it being in the same row as $s$.

Comment: @Vincent but I said there does not exist *any* combination of rows and column (also, I built $R$ such that it will only contain either a row containing $s$ *or* a column containing $s$), thus both row and column containing $s$ can't exist in $R$ by definition of $S$ and construction of $R$

Comment: The sentence between brackets is not true as written, we know very little about how you built $R$, for all we know you might take $R$ to be all rows and all columns. The thing that contains either a row or a column containing $s$ doesn't have a name yet, but let's call it $T$. There are many possible choices for $T$. Some of them will miss some 1's in $M$ and your claim is that there is one that doesn't. So the situation you *want* to rule out is: every choice of a subset $T$  of $R$ that still cover $S$ misses some element $x$, possibly dependent on the choice of $T$. (ctd below)

Comment: (continuation) what you *do* rule out is this: there is a 'universal' element $x$ that is missed by all possible choices of $T$. While it is true that no such $x$ exists, that is weaker than the statement that there is a $T$ that misses nothing.

Comment: How can $|R|$ be bigger  than $|S|$?

Comment: Here is an easy example: $M$ is a matrix $m \times n$ matrix whose top row is all 1's and the rest of the matrix is all zeroes. Any choice of $S$ consists of a single entry, so $|S| = 1$. If we are smart we take $R$ to be only the top row, and we have $|R| = |S| = 1$. But if we are not smart, we take $R$ to be the collection of all colums. Then the rows and columns in $R$ still together contain all the 1's in $M$, but in this case $|R| = n$ which (in general) is much bigger than $|S| = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**I edited my answer to make it more informative**

Here is a somewhat unsatisfactory proof as it reduces this theorem to another one about bipartite graphs without telling you anything about why that theorem is true. (But I'll provide a link where you can look it up.)

Make a bipartite graph: one set of vertices are the rows, one set of vertices are the columns and we draw an edge from vertex 'row i' to vertex 'column j' if and only there is a 1 in entry (i, j) of $M$.

Now 1's correspond to edges in the graph, and a collection of $1$'s with no common rows or columns correspond to a set of edges with no common vertices. Such a collection of edges is called a *matching*.

A set of rows and columns that together 'see' all 1's corresponds to a collection of vertices that together see all edges. Such a set of vertices is called a *vertex cover*.

In every graph we have (for obvious reasons) that the size of the biggest matching is less than or equal to the size of the smallest vertex cover. However, in *bipartite graphs* (of which the graph we constructed from our matrix $M$ is an example) we have the highly non-obvious fact that these sizes are actually equal. (This is called Konig's matching theorem and the proof can be found on page 41 in these lecture notes by Lex Schrijver: https://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/dict.pdf.

The equality given by Konigs theorem for the very particular graph coming from our matrix $M$ is exactly the equality you were asking about.